# Unable to get a particular route

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I need to be able to get all users details from the api. But i get the below error

```
Cannot GET /users
```

What do i need to correct in my code?

below is the code from the main js file

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const UserModel = require('./User.js')
const router = express.Router()

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('example app listening on port 3000')
    let db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://testuser:password123@ds149252.mlab.com:49252/assignment',{ useNewUrlParser: true })
})

let baseUrl = "http://localhost:3000"

let getAllUsers = (req, res) =>{
    UserModel.find()
        .exec((err, result)=>{
            if(err){
                console.log(err)
                res.send(err)
            } else if(result === undefined || result === null || result === ''){
                console.log("No Users Found")
                res.send("No Users Found")
            } else {
                console.log('All User Found')
                res.send(result)
            }
        })
} // end get all Users



app.get(baseUrl+'/users', getAllUsers)
app.get(baseUrl+'/users/:userId')

module.exports = (app);
```

Below is the mongoose structure i have set up

```
// importing mongoose module
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
// import schema 
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let userSchema = new Schema(
    {
        userId: {
            type: String,
            unique: true
        },
        firstName: {
            type: String,
            default: ''
        },
        lastName: {
            type: String,
            default: ''
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            default: ''
        }
    }
)

mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)
```

I should be getting an empty object or error saying "No Users Found"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need baseURL when defining routes with express. If you have followed the documentation you must have seen that

```
app.get('/users', getAllUsers);
```

is enough to define your route.

Also, you define a `Router` in your code but you don't use it.

Lastly, are you aware that your `db` variable defined in the `listen()` callback is unreachable anywhere ? It's defined inside the callback so it dies right after that function is called.